# Flyway upgrading 4.2.0 -> 5.0.0 migrate fails even with flyway.table specified

Tags: flyway

I'm updating a number of maven dependencies that have fallen behind in our application and am running into an issue upgrading from flyway-maven-plugin 4.2.0 where our reset and migrate make commands are failing in a way I can't find any helpful results for.

Initially I attempted to move from 4.2.0 to 5.2.4. When I was unable to resolve my error, I dropped back to a single version bump to 5.0.0. 
Following the release notes for 5.0.0, I have added `flyway.table=schema_version` to my flyway-$env.properties files and have updated my Makefile commands to use `-Dflyway.configFiles=`

When I attempt to migrate an existing DB flyway attempts to apply all scripts, causing a constraint violation on our initial db script. When attempting to migrate an empty DB flyway fails after running the initial script when it is unable to lock the `schema_version` table.

The make command executes the following:

```
@mvn -pl db flyway:repair \
    -Dflyway.url="jdbc:mysql://${FLYWAY_TARGET_HOST}:${FLYWAY_TARGET_PORT}/${FLYWAY_TARGET_DB}?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false" \
    -Dflyway.password=${FLYWAY_TARGET_DB_PW} \
    -Dflyway.user=${FLYWAY_TARGET_DB_USER} \
    -Dflyway.configFiles="src/main/resources/config/flyway/${FLYWAY_CONFIG_FILENAME}.properties"
@mvn -pl db flyway:migrate \
    -Dflyway.url="jdbc:mysql://${FLYWAY_TARGET_HOST}:${FLYWAY_TARGET_PORT}/${FLYWAY_TARGET_DB}?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false" \
    -Dflyway.password=${FLYWAY_TARGET_DB_PW} \
    -Dflyway.user=${FLYWAY_TARGET_DB_USER} \
    -Dflyway.configFiles="src/main/resources/config/flyway/${FLYWAY_CONFIG_FILENAME}.properties"
```

When run on an empty db, the following output is provided:

```
[INFO] --- flyway-maven-plugin:5.0.0:migrate (default-cli) @ db ---
[INFO] Flyway Community Edition 5.0.0 by Boxfuse
[INFO] Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_test (MySQL 5.7)
[INFO] Successfully validated 46 migrations (execution time 00:00.029s)
[INFO] Creating Schema History table: `db_test`.`schema_version`
[WARNING] Could not find schema history table `db_test`.`schema_version`, but found `db_test`.`schema_version` instead. You are seeing this message because Flyway changed its default for flyway.table in version 5.0.0 to flyway_schema_history and you are still relying on the old default (schema_version). Set flyway.table=schema_version in your configuration to fix this. This fallback mechanism will be removed in Flyway 6.0.0.
[INFO] Current version of schema `db_test`: << Empty Schema >>
[INFO] Migrating schema `db_test` to version 1.0 - DbBaseline
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.799 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-23T18:12:57-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:5.0.0:migrate (default-cli) on project db: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
[ERROR] Unable to lock table `db_test`.`schema_version`
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this with a clear head, the issue was in our V1.0 script, specifically that we were dropping and recreating the schema before creating the tables. This caused the flyway generated table to not be present after applying the V1.0 script.

After removing this line all flyway jobs execute without error. Luckily, the flyway:repair corrects the checksum in the `schema_version` table without any hacks or manual db editing.